# need to have driven / need to drive

Tags: meaning

> 1 How much time does one need to have driven a car before one can be
> considered a professional driver?
>
> 2 How much time does one need to drive a car before one can be
> considered a professional driver?

Do they mean the same?

Comment: Surely a 'professional driver' is someone who drives a vehicle for a living? It's not a measure of one's driving experience.

Comment: Kate, the point of the question is to compare "need to have driven" and "need to drive".

Comment: Well, I know that; my point was that neither sentence is very natural. Probably the first is better, because the question is about one's _past experience_ of driving.

Comment: There's nothing syntactically *incorrect* about #1 (the Perfect form). But it's pointless complexity, so I wouldn't endorse it. *How long do I have to live in this village to be accepted as a local resident?* is already a fairly complicated set of text elements. Why pile on the agony with *How long do I **have to have lived** in this village...?* I can't think of any context where the choice of verb form could affect the *meaning*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They could mean the same... but remember that 'means the same' isn't necessarily the same as 'interchangeable'. They use different tenses, so they would be used in different contexts, but the answer they might elicit could be the same.

'Have done' is the present perfect of the verb *to do*. It suggests that you have *just completed something*. So, example 1 might be said by somebody who is wondering if they have already racked up enough mileage to be considered as a professional. Example 2 is therefore more likely to be said by someone who is wondering what they yet have to do to meet the same condition.

Comment: "have driven" is not the present perfect here. It's the prefect infinitive.

Comment: The only context where I can see any point to the Perfect form is if the context is framed as "past in the future" *How much time **will** one need to **have driven** a car before...* Which is valid, but utterly pointless complexity. I still don't believe that any supposed difference in meaning could exist ***in the real world*** (as opposed to being capable of "described differently" simply because the verb tenses are different). All phrasings effectively mean the same thing, so learners should be advised to stick to the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

Sample sentences:

1 How much time does one need **to have driven a car** before one can be considered a professional driver?

2 How much time does one need **to drive a car** before one can be considered a professional driver?

Simplifying to how long:

1 **How long** does one need to **have driven** a car before one can be considered a professional driver?

You need to have driven a car as a racing car driver for at least three years. In other words, **the driving is in the past at the time of speaking**.

2 **How long** does one need to drive a car before one can be considered a professional driver?

You need to drive for at least three years. In other words, **the driving** (to become a professional driver) **has not yet taken place**.

["one" could be stated as "you", which is less formal)